# One or more problems with multiple where clauses in ASP LDAP query

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, active-directory

I have a script, written in ASP, that will list Active Directory users who aren't disabled. My query looks like this (but here I use a fake DN):

```
objCom.CommandText ="select givenName,sn,mail,telephonenumber,mobile,description,sAMAccountName,cn,UserAccountControl FROM 'LDAP://OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal' where UserAccountControl <> 514 OR where UserAccountControl <> 2 AND sAMAccountname ='*' ORDER by cn ASC"
```

The problem is that when I just have the one where statement it works fine and outputs the list of users but when I have both, the following message is returned

Provider error '80040e14'

One or more errors occurred during processing of command.

/ldap.asp, line 25

No idea what the problem is but I think, since it works with the one WHERE statement, that it is something to do with the query. Can you shed some light on this for me?

Comment: You've got a typo in the string...  `... where UserAccountControl <> 514 OR where UserAccountControl <> 2`, you've got two where's in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL syntax for multiple conditions is to use the appropriate boolean operators (`AND` or `OR`, generally, though others are possible) to string together the conditions, employing parentheses as needed. Don't repeat the `WHERE` clause: that would be just as wrong as repeating the `SELECT` or the `FROM`.

```
SELECT givenName, sn, mail, telephonenumber, mobile, description, sAMAccountName, cn, UserAccountControl 
FROM 'LDAP://OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal' 
WHERE UserAccountControl <> 514 OR UserAccountControl <> 2 AND sAMAccountname ='*' 
ORDER by cn ASC
```